# Parsing Xml in android using XmlPullParserFactory

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

```
<MyEvents>
<Tracking event="first">
<![CDATA[
http://www.myurl.com/test1
]]>
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="second">
<![CDATA[
http://www.myurl.com/test2
]]>
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="third">
<![CDATA[
http://www.myurl.com/test3
]]>
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="fourth">
<![CDATA[
http://www.myurl.com/test4
]]>
</Tracking>
<Tracking event="fifth">
<![CDATA[
http://www.myurl.com/test5
]]>
</Tracking>
</MyEvents>
```

I have this xml which i need to parse and store. As each node is named the same "Tracking" I dont know how to parse this xml. I want to parse and store urls corresponding with each event names(first, second, third, fourth and fifth in this case) in variables. I am using XMLPullParser and for other parts of this xml parsing was simple by making use of

```
if(myparser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tagname")){
                        //do something
                     }
```

in case of node with the same name but different event types i dont know how to parse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks as though you just need to look into handling attributes and filtering by that means through your parser.

Comment: Take a look at [`getAttributeValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeValue(int)) method.

Comment: if(parser.getAttributeValue("second",null) != null)
{
 //do something      
 }
something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may declare a inner class like this:

```
static class Track {
    String event;
    String url;
}
```

Then, the parsing code:

```
List<Track> allTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();

myparser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "MyEvents");
while (myparser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    if (myparser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        continue;
    }
    String name = myparser.getName();
    if (name.equals("Tracking ")) {
        String event = myparser.getAttributeValue(0); // I'm supposing that there is just one
        myparser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Tracking ");
        String url = null;
        if (myparser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            url = parser.getText();
            myparser.nextTag();
        }
        Track track = new Track();
        track.event = event;
        track.url = url;
        allTracks.add(track);
    }
}
```

It's not perfectly but should get a list of tracks, each one with its respective url and event.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your timely help and the snippet. it helped a lot.